# Drag Leave and Drag Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I drag a file over to my window I wish to show an overlay, and when the file is dragged off the window I wish to remove the overlay.

```
$(window).on('dragleave', this.onDragLeave);

$(window).on('dragenter', this.onDragEnter);

p.onDragEnter = function(e) {

    console.log('ENTER');
};


p.onDragLeave = function(e) {
        console.log('LEAVE');
};
```

The above works fine, when I enter and leave the window it logs correctly.

The problem starts when I start fading in and out my overlay:

```
p.onDragEnter = function(e) {

    console.log('ENTER');
    $('#drag-overlay').fadeIn();
};


p.onDragLeave = function(e) {
        console.log('LEAVE');
        $('#drag-overlay').fadeOut();
};
```

With the above, it just fades in and out again and again. I'm not sure whats going on, it's as if when the overlay fades in it fires a drag leave, i'm not sure why?

The overlay is just an absolute div, width and height 100%.

Comment: Please post a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). You'd get an answer much quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by showing an overlay, you are causing the dragged item to leave the parent and drag into the overlay. Then hiding the overlay causes drag to trigger in the parent.

Fortunately, the solution is simple and can be done in css:

```
#drag-overlay
{
    pointer-events: none;
    ...
}
```

See **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SL2fK/1/)** for a working solution.

If you remove `pointer-events:none` you get the same behaviour. `pointer-events:none` just means that the parent ondragleave method isn't fired when dragging over the overlay.

Comment: Thanks, onDragEnter is the name of my method so nothing to worry about. This worked, thanks.